# Swf is not loaded as centered when using TLF text and getting stage null in AIR2.6

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, air, flash-cs5

When SWF loaded, it is not loads SWF centered with TLF text using & getting stage null. If classic normal text used then it is load centered.

please suggest how to load SWF as centered with TLF text in AIR 2.6. I have written a code as follows.

```
package {
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.Event;

public class FullScreen extends Sprite {

    public function FullScreen() {

        this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, _onAddedToStage);

        btnClose.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btnCloseFun);
    }

    private function _onAddedToStage(e:Event):void {

        txt.text= "This is text";

        var screenBounds:Rectangle = Screen.mainScreen.visibleBounds;

        stage.nativeWindow.x = screenBounds.width/2 - stage.stageWidth/2;
        stage.nativeWindow.y = screenBounds.height/2 - stage.stageHeight/2;

        this.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, _onAddedToStage);
    }           

    function btnCloseFun(event:MouseEvent):void {
        stage.nativeWindow.close(); 
    }
}
```

}

Flash file properties is width=800, height = 600

[image]

[image]

Comment: Trace that `Screen.mainScreen.visibleBounds`, probably you're getting nulls in there.

Comment: @Vesper its not getting null..Its running fine..But not loaded center first